# How to get value from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome-extension

Can I get a value on a local web app from chrome extension? I'm going to use selenium and run the facebook pixel helper extension. Is it possible to decide if the loading website uses facebook pixel on code using facebook pixel chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Although, you don't have to use the Facebook Pixel Chrome Extension. Just check the web page source for a script element which contains this string 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'.

Comment: Hi Balsa. This website doesn't load fbevents.js, but the facebook pixel helper extension says it has facebook pixel. Do you have an idea?

https://www.flynanceair.com/